# Виснет Ubuntu при build project

Tags: c++, ubuntu

Пытаюсь установить с гитхаба проект на Ubuntu 22.04 [Aerostack2 Project](https://aerostack2.github.io/_00_getting_started/source_install.html#getting-started-ubuntu-installation-source)
При colcon build --symlink-install, начинается билд но на 4 этапе Ubuntu просто зависает. Использую эмулятор VirtualBox. В чем может быть проблема?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1) Проверьте что это не банальный ждущий режим из-за бездействия внутри виртуалки; 2) Проверьте что виртуалке хватает выделенной памяти

Comment: 1) Нет 2) Я тестил с объемом памяти и в 5гб и в 12, результат 0

Comment: Возможно проблема в том, что пытаюсь запустить билдить через виртуалку, но не уверен

Comment: Ничто не должно мешать билдить в виртуалке (а иногда билдить в виртуалке это единственный возможный вариант)

Comment: попробовал билдить через CLI, такая же история, только уже зависает не на 4/24 этапе, а на 7/24.

Comment: У меня собралось без зависаний https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmny1.png (правда, у меня хост тоже на линуксе)

Comment: Правда, меня смущает «11 ongoing» на скриншоте — у меня до такого большого числа вроде не доходило. Попробуйте [какую-нибудь опцию](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/reference/executor-arguments.html) типа `--parallel-workers 1` или даже `--executor sequential`, вдруг это поможет снизить нагрузку на виртуалку

Comment: Ничего не изменилось( Может я что-то не так делаю? Вы все делали точно по шагам расписанным на сайте? Просто я профан в этом деле

Comment: Проблема решилась, нужно было прописать обе опции: --parallel-workers 1 --executor sequential

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась, нужно было прописать обе опции: --parallel-workers 1 --executor sequential